# Removing RTTI from Boost::Interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

I'm trying to use Boost::Interprocess for shared memory. However, my program also requires the use of LLVM, and LLVM requires fno-rtti, while Boost::Interprocess requires RTTI. Specifically, I tried the first example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html), and I got compilation errors:

> /usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/in_place_interface.hpp:50:71: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
>             :  in_place_interface(::boost::alignment_of::value, sizeof(T), typeid(T).name())

My solution to this was to browse through the Boost::Interprocess headers and replace each `typeid().name()` with the string constant `"sometype"`. The example now compiles and runs fine (as far as I can tell). My poorly-understood impression is that Boost::Interprocess uses typenames to index a map, as an optimization to speedup lookups. Under my poorly-understood impression, changing all typenames to be constant will give a performance penalty, but won't impact correctness.

If I don't remove RTTI from Boost::Interprocess, I will be forced to use some other interprocess library, because [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/mixing_sources_with_rtti_on_and_.html) doesn't give me a lot of hope for mixing RTTI and no-RTTI.

Is this replacement, of nuking RTTI in the Boost::Interprocess headers by replacing `typeid` with constant strings, ok? I'm worried about incorrect behavior, such as Boost using the typeid to determine which destructor to call, or other such issues. I'm on a single-developer, single-purpose virtual machine.

Comment: Why `LLVM requires fno-rtti,`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And I finally solve it by recompile LLVM with LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON.